# Is there any way to bypass compressing video process while importing from video library with Cordova plugin camera?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

We are using the plugin to select videos from the gallery and import it into our application.

Our application needs mp4 files and our users will only import mp4 files as well. At present, the plugin works fine, but it coverts the mp4 video to .mov file and then we have to reconvert it to .mp4. Which takes lot of time and is not needed.

So, is there a property or something that we can set to bypass this process to coverting the .mp4 video to .mov file and instead use the original video that was imported from library?

Thanks in advance for your help.